# Glitch effect with CSS3 & jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, effect

How is this glitch effect created? [SEE GIF ANIMATION BELOW]

[image]

Source:
https://jigsaw.google.com/

Can we re-create the Glitch Effect in CSS3 & jQuery?

Here's a **codepen** which I started : http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/yeWzrQ

```
Any Help would be appreciated!
```

Comment: The JavaScript part of your codepen is empty.

Comment: Its coming from the jigsaw.min.js I have a spaced version but its still unclear to me where its trigger...

Comment: And it is using: [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite) checkout the examples

Comment: @YoramdeLangen Yeah.. looks like they minified the js.. Thanks for the Tweenlite link, will checkout.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm stuck how to start :P

Answer (score 0):

You inspect/watch what happens in your browser (rightclick - inspect).
Its fast but it looks like they:

- create copies of the element
- shrink the copies so that the text is croped
- rearange the copies slightly

It's like making carbon-copies of a foto, cutting them to pieces and rearanging them.

Comment: Thanks. hard-coding that would be a mess.. Any idea how to keep in simple and modular?